# Pull subset of large data by multiple specific characters

Tags: r, subset, extract, lapply

I have a large database which divides files into chunks for ease of analysis/storage and I am trying to extract multiple specific values stored in the character format from a single column to take a chunk of the overall data for further analysis.

Within these files I am interested in pulling ALL rows in which column "Cat" is equals any number of characters (different for each pull and each file).

Files are set up (for example) as:

```
2001_x.sas
2002_x.sas
....
2018_x.sas
```

Currently, I am doing the following:

```
#Create a list of files- fill out pattern to chose specific files with similar names
    'x<-list.files(pattern = "_x.sas")'
#Read and subset files when Cat is C21 C98 or D27 etc 
    'z<-lapply(x, function(x) {
      a<-read.sas(x)
      c<-subset(a, (Cat=="C21" | Cat=="C98 | Cat=="D27))
      })'

#Bind df's into master df
    'y<-bind_rows(z)'
```

y is then a really nice pull from multiple files at once. The advantage of this, as the total dataset is several terabytes, is that this works within the individual files and doesn't overwhelm the memory on my desktop.

The problem is that I can't always use Cat equals variable with just three values. Sometimes, I need to input hundreds of values, which is very tedious. I have tried replacing this with lists or vectors.

Ideally, I'd like the code to look more like this, if you know what I mean, but this doesnt work:

```
'b<-List or vector with character values of interest
z<-lapply(x, function(x) { a<-read.sas(x) subset(a, Cat==any(b)) }) 
y<-bind_rows(z)'
```

Such that any value in list b would be included in the subset if it equals Cat. However, I've only been able to get this to work with Cat equals variable and the or symbol.

Thanks!

Comment: you should do `subset(a, grepl(paste0("^",b,"$", collapse = "|"), Cat))`

Comment: THANK YOU! This worked perfectly.